# Replace occuring img tag / tags with itself but append some string in a given string

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

i want to replace img tags in a string. Replacing an img tag and add for example an a[href] tag works fine with a dom parser but this won't help me as i have to alter the tags in an existing string of html. I know that altering html with regex isn't a good idea but i can't figure out how to change img tags as whole in a string of html. Beside that i need to wrap the tag in an a[href] where the [href] is provided via a property of the img tag.

```
<img class="myclasses" width="100" src="mysource" data-image-src="another_src">
```

After the "transformation" any img tag found should look like this:

```
<a href="another_src"><img [...] src="http://myexample.me[mysource]"></a>
```

I got it to work if one image is in the string but failed to handle two images.

I hope someone could help me out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably achieve what you need using `preg_replace_callback` and then looping through the image's attributes in the callback function.

So for example, given this test string:

```
$content= <<<HTML
<img alt="image-alt-2" src="image-path" style="width: 20px; height: 15px; border: 1px solid red;" title="image-title" data-image-src="another_src" />
    <p>Some other tags. These shouldn\'t be changed<br />Etc.</p>
<img alt="image-alt-2" src="image-path-2" style="width: 35px; height: 30px;" title="another-image-title" data-image-src="somewhere_else" />
HTML;
```

We can then match out the images and call our replacement function:

```
$content= preg_replace_callback('/<img ((?:[-a-z]+="[^"]*"\s*)+)\/>/i', 'replaceImage', $content);
```

For my example I'm just removing the `data-image-src` attribute and using it to create the link, everything else is left as it was:

```
function replaceImage($matches) {
    // matches[0] will contain all the image attributes, need to split
    // those out so we can loop through them
    $submatches= array();
    $donelink= false;
    $count= preg_match_all('/\s*([-a-z]+)="([^"]*)"/i', $matches[1], $submatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    $result= '<img ';

    for($ndx=0;$ndx<sizeof($submatches);$ndx++) {
        if ($submatches[$ndx][1]=='data-image-src') {
            // Found the link attribute, prepend the link to the result
            $result= "<a href=\"{$submatches[$ndx][2]}\">$result";
            $donelink= true; // We've added a link, remember to add the closing </a>
        }
        // You can handle anything else you want to change on an attribute-by-attribute basis here
        else {
            // Something else, just pass it through
            $result.= $submatches[$ndx][0];
        }
    }

    return "$result/>".($donelink?'</a>':'');
}
```

Running that on the sample content gives:

```
<a href="another_src"><img alt="image-alt-2" src="image-path" style="width: 20px; height: 15px; border: 1px solid red;" title="image-title"/></a>
    <p>Some other tags. These shouldn\'t be changed<br />Etc.</p>
<a href="somewhere_else"><img alt="image-alt-2" src="image-path-2" style="width: 35px; height: 30px;" title="another-image-title"/></a>
```

Hope that helps!